# Cross platform simple TCP/ IP API?

Tags: c++

I'm making a simple cross platform chat program. I'm using wXWidgets for the GUI which works well, but I need a way to create a socket and to create a server client setup. Is there an API that for example underlying uses WinSock on Windows, and Linux's native socket and osx's?

I'm not looking for boost as a solution because I will be making it open sourced and not everyone feels like installing a 70+ MB library.

Comment: it's kinda sad if a c++ developer couldn't be bothered to install boost

Comment: When I make personal projects I use Boost, but if they are open source or library projects I avoid it because I rarely see libraries that depend on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [QtNetwork](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.2/qtnetwork.html) module

Comment: if the OP considers boost too large of a dependency, I don't think Qt would be any lighter...

Comment: yeah QT is pretty large, however statically linking only the required libraries will reduce the final size of the executable

Answer (score 6):

Winsock is quite compatible with the POSIX socket APIs, and most of the standard functions are available in both. The headers are named differently, but a simple `#ifdef` can solve that:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <winsock2.h>
#else
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
// other headers you may use
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

wxWidgets itself has TCP client/server classes: see [here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__class__net.html)

Answer (score 0):

How about Apache Runtime?  Here is the page detailing socket definitions:

[http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/trunk/group_*apr*_network__io.html](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/trunk/group__apr__network__io.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this seven years old question in the hope that this helps someone, someday (:

I have failed to find a cross-platform, **lightweight** API on sockets. (There is poco, boost asio and others out there, but they are big, comprehensive and complex libraries)

So I made a simple (and not complete) wrapper on POSIX sockets and Winsock here: https://github.com/soroush/libcpnet